# It's the end of the world as we know it

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

You wake up in a daze... Your head is pounding and your vision is a
bit hazy... 
You're in some sort of room... Steel walls, no windows, a
single door and a piece of paper nailed to the wall...  
Above that you
can make out a rusted sign that reads: "Welcome to ..." below it
someone seems to have spray painted something... does that say "HLFGS
GSVM VZHG"?

**Where am I?**

You look at the note and try to make out what it says but it's all
sorts of messed up... Maybe it's your vision or maybe it's some sort
of clue as to your escape... Wait a second... Numbers?

---

> qɐsɥıuƃ ʎonɹ ɥǝɐp ʍou,ʇ ɥǝןd qnʇ soɯǝʇɥıuƃ ǝןsǝ ɯɐʎ

---

> (0 + 1) (1.5 + 2.5) Join.
>
> (33 - 14) (26.3 - 5.3) Remove from.
>
> (13 * 1) (7 * 3) Else.
>
> (12 / 3) (54 / 6) Incapable of.
>
> (2 + 2) (5.5 + 3.5) Sounds like also.
>
> (53 - 51) (29.7 - 9.7) Single.
>
> (3 * 4) (4 * 5) Recognized.
>
> (66 / 3) (36 / 4) Act.
>
> (6.8 + 13.2) (2 + 7) Mathematical objects.
>
> (13.5 -(-4.5)) (7 - 6) Another name for fingers.
>
> (3 * 3) (4 * 4) Alpha Sierra.
>
> (19 / 1) (99 / 11) Together.
>
> (6 * 2) (45 * 1/5) Quickly.
>
> (4.6 + 10.4) (9.1 + 4.9) Within proximity.
>
> (1/3 * 9) (1 * 1) Procreate.
>
> (9 - 6) (37.6 - 17.6) Where are you ____?
>
> (75 / 5) (28 / 2) Absence of things.
>
> (2 * 10) (1 * 9) With purpose of.
>
> (16 - 7) (22 - 7) (20 - 6) A different one.
>
> (5 * 3) (2 * 7) Fauna.

---

> fhvgsvliwvigsvburihgxlnvrmmlgblfifhfzokilxvhh

---

> (35.1568 41.8432) (86.736 63.736) (8 20) (963.9 18.9)

Comment: To save others the neck pain: The upside down text reads "bashing your head wont help but something else may"

Comment: @EngineerToast But that's part of the fun :) It's a little more than flipped but you're correct.

Comment: Each individual letter is mirrored in two directions, right? I caught that but didn't detail it in the comment.

Comment: Flipped upside down and reverse lettering

Comment: 56/6 -- really?

Comment: (and is it deliberate that that one appears twice?)

Comment: The first one just got edited but not the second one...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first few steps were solved by [Engineer Toast](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/50653/18250) and [Sconibulus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/50655/18250), I got the final part, after the line.

The upside down text gives

> "bashing your head won't help but something else may", giving the AT*BASH* cipher

So using Atbash on the ciphertext gives

> usetheordertheyfirstcomeinnotyourusualprocess

or

> Use the order they first come in, not your usual process

and

> SOUTH THEN EAST

---

This is referring to maths. The 'usual process' in maths is:

> BIDMAS/BODMAS/Whatever you call it

But we aren't supposed to use that.

By solving the sums on each line, ([Engineer Toast's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/50653/18250) gives a full list), we end up with two numbers.

If we use A1Z26 on the numbers we get (thanks @Techidiot for providing this:)

> 1 4 Join.
> A D
>
> 19 21 Remove from.
> S U
>
> 13 21 Else.
> M U
>
> 4 9 Incapable of.
> D I
>
> 4 9 Sounds like also.
> D I
>
> 2 20 Single.
> B T
>
> 12 20 Recognized.
> L T
>
> 22 9 Act.
> V I
>
> 20 9 Mathematical objects.
> T I
>
> 18 1 Another name for fingers.
> R A
>
> 9 16 Alpha Sierra.
> I P
>
> 19 9 Together.
> S I
>
> 12 9 Quickly.
> L I
>
> 15 14 Within proximity.
> O N
>
> 3 1 Procreate.
> C A
>
> 3 20 Where are you ____?
> C T
>
> 15 14 Absence of things.
> O N
>
> 20 9 With purpose of.
> T I
>
> 9 15 14 A different one.
> I O N
>
> 15 14 Fauna.
> O N

This can be added together to get the following order of mathematical processes:

> ADDITION
> Join Sounds like also Mathematical objects Within proximity
> Join two (sounds like too) integers within proximity
>
> SUBTRACTION
> Remove from Single Another name for fingers Where are you ____? A different one
> Remove a single digit from another
>
> MULTIPLICATION
> Else Recognized Alpha sierra Quickly Procreate With purpose of Fauna
> Otherwise known as reproduce for animals
>
> DIVISION
> Incapable of Act Together Absence of things
> Can't be done with nothing (x/0 = error)

And applying this order to the 4 numbers at the bottom gives the following:

> (35.1568 41.8432) ADDITION = 77
>  (86.736 63.736) SUBTRACTION = 23
>  (8 20) MULTIPLICATION = 160
>  (963.9 18.9) DIVISION = 51

So we now have the phrase 'South the East' and the numbers 77, 23, 160 and 51.

Using these as coordinates (77°23' S 160°51' E) gives the final answer. You are in the

> [APOCALYPSE PEAKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocalypse_Peaks) in Antarctica, which matches the title.

Comment: Two tidbits: 1 is you can get the full words, not just the first 2 letters. 2nd us the coords give a specific place that makes the title make sense.

Comment: @n_palum ah ok, for 2 google maps doesn't show Antarctica, just the continent

Comment: If you get the full words figured out - I will give you the location I have since you've otherwise figured it out

Comment: I'm feeling very dim. What is the connection between "Else" and "multiplication", between "incapable of" and "division", and between "sounds like also" and "division"? And are all the later "clues" just red herrings?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan The letters **MU** **SU** etc correspond to their values obtained by arithmetic operations. I'm not sure if they relate in any other way. Also, not sure about how the other clues play their part as the puzzle is solved without that.

Comment: If you take them based on the operations, (take all the + together, the / together etc), and then get words based off the clues they are a phrase that loosely defines the arithmetic operator. The numbers as was figured out, spell out the entire word if taken in the groups again.

Comment: Oh, I see now. D'oh.

Answer (score 4):

Partial Helpers:

The spray-painted text "HLFGS GSVM VZHG" may be

> SOUTH THEN EAST as that is a valid crytpogram found by [quipqipu](http://quipqiup.com/)

The upside-down text (also each letter is mirrored) reads:

> bashing your head wont help but something else may

The list of arithmetic problems resolved to:

> (1)(4) Join.
>  (19)(21) Remove from.
>  (13)(21) Else.
>  (4)(9) Incapable of.
>  (4)(9) Sounds like also.
>  (2)(20) Single.
>  (12)(20) Recognized.
>  (22)(9) Act.
>  (20)(9) Mathematical objects.
>  (18)(1) Another name for fingers.
>  (9)(16) Alpha Sierra.
>  (19)(9) Together.
>  (12)(9) Quickly.
>  (15)(14) Within proximity.
>  (3)(1) Procreate.
>  (3)(20) Where are you ____?
>  (15)(14) Absence of things.
>  (20)(9) With purpose of.
>  (9)(15)(14) A different one.
>  (15)(14) Fauna.
>
>  The oddball here is the second-to-last line because there are three values.

The text makes me think of crossword puzzle clues and the numbers *could* be locations of the answers in a grid but I can't make that fit in any reasonable way. There are a lot of repeated values. For instance, `Within proximity` and `Fauna` both have the same numbers preceding their text.

Comment: Er, I thought we're in a daze, not a maze ...

Comment: @Ankoganit Errr... Maybe I'm the one in a daze, then, thinking it said maze.

Comment: May be the numbers are just letter values.

Answer (score 2):

*Partial*

The upside-down text yields

> "bashing your head won't help but something else may" which implies the ATBASH cipher

Applying said cipher to the ciphertexts yield

> South Then East

and

> usetheordertheyfirstcomeinnotyourusualprocess